# VBScript - Passing schtasks command into run method

Tags: vbscript, runtime-error, windows-task-scheduler

The following .vbs creates the desired task without any issue (please excuse the syntax):

```
Option Explicit

Dim wshell
Set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshell.Run "schtasks /create /sc once /tn ""Reminder"" /tr ""C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe \""/c title Alert & mode con: cols=40 lines=10 & color f0 & cls & echo *** Message goes here *** & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo Press any key to exit & pause > nul\"""" /st 18:00 /sd 08/20/2016 /f"
```

However if I try pass the `schtasks` command string via a variable as follows:

```
Option explicit
dim strdate, strtime, strmessage, strtask, wshell

strdate = "08/20/2016"
strtime = "18:30"
strmessage = "Turn off pump"

WScript.Echo strdate
WScript.Echo strtime
WScript.Echo strmessage

strtask = """schtasks /create /sc once /tn """"Reminder"""" /tr """"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe \""""/c title Alert & mode con: cols=40 lines=10 & color f0 & cls & echo " & strmessage & " & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo Press any key to exit & pause > nul"""""""" /st " & strtime & " /sd " & strdate & " /f""" & " ,0" & " ,true"

WScript.Echo strtask

Set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshell.Run strtask
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I can't understand why I'm getting this, the variable being parsed is, after all, identical to the previous snippet (including the quotes)... Could someone please explain to me what I'm missing?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Ansgar Wiechers' guidance. I've managed to get a working, albeit inelegant, script by removing the run command options, and intrinsically checking for an external command error instead. See hereunder:

```
option explicit
dim strdate, strtime, strmessage, strtask, exitcode, wshell

strdate = "08/21/2016"
strtime = "13:45"
strmessage = "Turn off pump"

WScript.Echo strdate
WScript.Echo strtime
WScript.Echo strmessage

strtask = "schtasks /create /sc once /tn ""Reminder"" /tr ""C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe \""/c title Alert & mode con: cols=40 lines=10 & color f0 & cls & echo " & strmessage & " & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo Press any key to exit & pause > nul\"""" /st " & strtime & " /sd " & strdate & " /f"

set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
exitcode = wshell.Run(strtask, 0, True)
if exitcode <> 0 
then WScript.Echo "External command failed: " & Hex(exitcode)
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seriously doubt that your original command ever worked. The nested quotes around the argument list to `CMD.exe` should always have made it raise an error. Remove those nested quotes (leave just the double quotes around the entire CMD statement) and also remove the arguments to the `Run` method from `strTask`, and task creation should work as you expect.

```vb
strtask = "schtasks /create /sc once /tn ""Reminder""" & _
          " /tr ""C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c title Alert" & _
          " & mode con: cols=40 lines=10 & color f0 & cls" & _
          " & echo " & strmessage & _
          " & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo." & _
          " & echo Press any key to exit & pause > nul""" & _
          " /sd " & strdate & " /st " & strtime & " /f"

exitcode = wshell.Run(strtask, 0, True)

If exitcode <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "External command failed: " & Hex(exitcode)
End If
```

It's always a good idea to add some code to check the exit status of external commands, so you can detect if something went wrong.

With that said, you could greatly improve maintainability of this code with some modifications:

- Don't create the commandline as one big string. Build it from the inside out.
- Use environment variables if possible (e.g. `%COMSPEC%` instead of the literal path to `CMD.exe`)
- Use quotes only where they're required.
- Use a quoting function for adding escaped double quotes.

```vb
Function qq(str)
  qq = """" & str & """"
End Function

cmdargs = "/c title Alert & mode con: cols=40 lines=10 & color f0 & cls" & _
          " & echo " & strmessage & " & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo." & _
          " & echo. & echo. & echo. & echo Press any key to exit & pause > nul"
strtask = "schtasks /create /f /sc once /tn Reminder" & _
          " /tr " & qq("%COMSPEC% " & cmdargs) & _
          " /sd " & strdate & " /st " & strtime

exitcode = wshell.Run(strtask, 0, True)
```

Better yet, put the batch code into an actual batch file:

```batch
@echo off
title Alert
mode con: cols=40 lines=10
color f0
cls
echo %~1
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Press any key to exit
pause > nul
```

and create the task to run that batch file with your message:

```vb
Function qq(str)
  qq = """" & Replace(str, """", "\""") & """"
End Function

batchfile = "C:\path\to\your.bat"
strtask   = "schtasks /create /f /sc once /tn Reminder" & _
            " /tr " & qq(qq(batchfile) & " " & qq(strmessage)) & _
            " /sd " & strdate & " /st " & strtime

exitcode = wshell.Run(strtask, 0, True)
```

Comment: I very much appreciate your help. I will definitely employ error checking in my script (i.e. in checking the status of the external command - I can do this with the `on error` statement as well right?) I am choosing not to use a batch file, though it is clearly the best option, despite the complications I prefer executing everything in one file... I do have a follow-up question, if I may, Why does `strtask` parse only when I add the run command options later?

Comment: For external commands you need to check their exit code as shown in my answer. `On Error` controls error handling of VBScript errors only. It doesn't know about errors of external commands. Your followup question is answerd by the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). The `Run` method takes a command string and two other options. It doesn't parse these options out of the command string.